# An error when using log10_trans() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation

I have a dataframe `testlist` that has three columns: "`Time Point`" "`G1`" and "`G2`"

I run this ggplot line on it, having "`Time point`" as y-axis.

```
testplot <- ggplot(testlist, aes_string(x = "G1", y = "`Time Point`")) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient()+
  scale_x_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),#,
                     limits = c(10^1,10^4),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x,n = 2))
```

With G1, it runs and plots my data. With G2 however, I get this error:

```
Error in if (!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x)/1.34))) (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) ||  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Both data sets G1 and G2 are continuous points of about 70500. The only thing that differs is the ranges:

```
G1: -16.34 to 54454
G2: -131.25 to 4675
```

I think this has to do with applying the transformation on negative numbers, but both sets have negative numbers. I also get this warning messages regardless if it plots or not:

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT1: I am having trouble making a minimal example.
I will attempt another edit with an example.

EDIT2: Here is a link to the CSV file: [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1777x1liI6pSS1SUr4l-7b3dnoPTG_tc8/view?usp=sharing)

- having 'Time point' as y, PEA as x shows the error; PIA as x graphs the data.

EDIT3: The log function produces -inf values in the dataframe, ggplot will not use those values. I will update the post what end up doing about it.

Comment: Is there a chance we could have a [mcve]?

Comment: I am having a difficult time creating a minimal example; I can attach a .csv file, but that is not really a minimal reproducible example. Thanks though.

Comment: A link to a CSV file is not minimal but is far better than nothing.

Comment: @BenBolker I lined a CSV. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: huh, I'm getting a bunch of weird problems, will have to come back to this later, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in failure is because one contains zeros and the other doesn't. NaNs from taking the log of a negative number are removed in the density plot function but -inf from log of zero isn't. The `ggridges` layer fails because it uses the standard deviation to set the bandwidth, and the standard deviation when the vector contains -inf is NaN. There's no reason to not remove negatives/zeros if you want to use a log transformation, but you could keep it as is if you input the arguments `from` and `bandwidth` into the `ggridges` geom.